# Is it possible to automate the creation of components in SDL Tridion using data from an excel worksheet?

Tags: core-service, api

Is it possible to automate the process of creating components in Tridion using data from an excel sheet?

If so, what are the SDL Tridion API's I can use for this and how would I go about this?

Currently, I have no idea how to proceed.

Your input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You might find [tridion.se] useful, but you'll want to work on your grammar and spelling. I'm moving this question at the request of a moderator there, who will hopefully be willing to help you out with the latter...

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange! Creating Tridion components from data in an excel worksheet is definitely possible using core services. Ryan Durkin has a blog post on this that may help get you started: http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/creating-custom-pages-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011

Answer (score 4):

Yes 100%

Assuming you are using Tridion 2011 or later, SDL Tridion Core Service is the interface to interact with the content management system.

You can start with Ryan's blog post, which matches your requirements pretty closely:

http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/creating-custom-pages-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011/

Ryan also has several other posts for more advanced topics such as creating images, keywords and pages via Core Service.

http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/author/rdurkin/

To get started, take a look at my starter project here:

http://www.mrgn.co/2013/10/sdl-tridion-core-service-sample/